# Software to cut video without saving a new file

Tags: windows-xp, video-editing

I need a application to cut video files. I have tried some applications and they require me to save the cut video into a new file rather than overwriting the original file.

This is quite annoying because I won't regret cutting those junk part of a video and I wish to save it and overwrite it.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: What platform is this for?

Comment: Windows xp....words limit...

Comment: I doubt that you are going to get a positive answer for this.

Comment: Which programs did you try? If it is a free, open-source app, you can post a request to provide an option to do that. If it is a commercial app that you paid for, then you can post a request to provide an option to do that.

Answer (score 4):

When you are cutting a video, you are really just pointing how where you would like the new clip to start and stop - it doesn't actually create the new cut video file until you save it.

At this point, it reads the original video file, and writes a new one based on the cuts you have decided upon.

This is why you cannot overwrite the original, it is required during the saving process.

Comment: They should write a temp file for that, then overwrite the original one with the temp file, and delete the temp file.

Comment: @gunbuster363, yes they could do that, but since unlike text files, videos are large and re-acquiring them if you decide you did want it would be a big hassle, they leave the original file alone. Can you not simply move the new file and overwrite the original?

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is automating the process of replacing the file after its done, you could use any software you want that provides a line command (such as [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr)) and use any shell script to do it for you. Being in windows, use a [batch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) such as this:

```
handbrakecli ref=1:weightp=1:subq=2:rc-lookahead=10:trellis=0:8x8dct=0 -i %1.mp4 -o %1.tmp
del %1.mp4
ren %1.tmp %1.mp4
```